# Содержит ли массив все элементы другого массива?

Tags: java, android, массивы

```
int[] m1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, };
int[] m2 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, };
```

Необходимо проверить содержит ли массив `m2` все элементы массива `m1`

Додумал такое решение:

```
  private Boolean checkRun(int[] a, int[] b) {
    List<Integer> list_A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
        list_A.add(a[index]);
    }

    Boolean ret = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if(list_A.contains(b[i])) {
            ret = true;
        }
        else {
            // не содержит что то
            ret = false;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Какая сложность? Какие требования? Что именно у вас не получилось?

Comment: После ret = false сразу делайте return.

Comment: @pavel признаться не знаю что ответить на вопрос о сложности и о требованиях. Мне важно понять принцип, по сути реальная задача выглядит именно так как она описана выше. 
Немного подумав пришло в голову решение, подскажите пожалуйста верно ли составлен алгоритм?

Comment: @pavel выходит что мне необходимо убрать `return ret;` из конца и перенести его под `ret = false;` ? Просто IDE ругается, разве так можно делать?

Comment: Чем не устраивает containsAll?

Comment: @YuraIvanov не додумался.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
   public boolean isContain(int[] m1, int[] m2){
        int count = 0;
        for (int a : m1) for (int b : m2) if (a == b) {
            count++; break;
        }
        return count == m1.length;
    }
```

### Пример - 1:

```
    int[] m1 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] m2 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    System.out.println(isContain(m1,m2));
```

Вывод: true

---

### Пример - 2:

```
int[] m1 = new int[]{1, 8, 3, 4};
int[] m2 = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2};
System.out.println(isContain(m1,m2));
```

Вывод: false

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.

Answer (score 1):

1)Создаете массив размера равного самому большому из двух (назовем его `m3`)

2)Тип boolean(все элементы = false)

3)В цикле пробегаете, сравнивая элементы, если элементы совпадают - в ячейке массива `m3` устанавливаете значение true.

4)В конце проверяете массив `m3` на то, что все элементы равны true - если это так, значит содержит.
Иначе нет.

Так я решил бы эту задачу.

Но учтите, здесь не будут решать задачи с нуля и до конца за Вас. Ровно как и дописывать курсовые\дипломы.

Comment: Медленно, можно сделать за О(n+m) вместо O(n*m) )

Comment: @pavel если посмотрите на условие - два простых массива из 4 и 6 элементов. Думаю, это просто задача из университета и не для работы, где собственно О не важна.

Comment: @Asgard задача из реальной жизни, никакого университета, но O и правда не так важна, элементов не много.